# Where can I find US public company bankruptcy data

Tags: data, historical-data, database

I am doing a thesis about firm survival in time of crisis (2008-2009) and I would like to know where can I find publicly available database about company bankruptcy.

Since I have thousands of companies, it will be very crucial if the database is such that I can upload all of my indexes in one file rather than searching the companies one by one and writing down the bankruptcy date.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The Harvard Bankrupcy Data Project tries to do exactly that, they seem to have data for the specified time frame, but unfortunately I cannot vouch for its accuracy.

http://bdp.law.harvard.edu/filingsdb.cfm

edit: They don't seem to offer the full data any more, so that indeed won't work for you.

You could instead try this one, one of the sources for the Harvard data:
http://lopucki.law.ucla.edu/sample_download.htm

Comment: Hi phi, thanks for the link. I went on the site and made a request, but it gave me the total number of bankruptcies for the specific period, so is it possible to get each bankruptcy and its date and company ticker? thanks

Comment: You're right, my mistake. Check the other one.

Comment: Thanks for the new link, I went there and made a request for them to send me the data. Do you know how much time it will take before they respond? thanks